# How to redefine shape of query in Apollo GraphQl after a response

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

Working with apollo is great but how can you change the shape of the response from a query. I am using reactjs to display user details and their music information

Say I have a query

```
query {
 userDetails {
  id,
  name,
  music {
   name,
   type
  }
}
```

is there a way to change the shape using apollo (not in reactjs) to something like

```
query {
 userDetails {
  id,
  name,
  musicName,
  musicType
 }
}
```

so that I get the second shape as the response rather than the first, then which I will have to change it using reactjs

Comment: I don't think this is achievable. GraphQL defines the entity and its responsibility is to return that entity when requested. The responsibility of transforming the entity to the desired shape should be of the component/service that uses it.

Comment: ohh, Okay means I will just have to continue doing what I have been doing

Answer (score 3):

You can create [local-only](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/managing-state-with-field-policies/) fields that reads from the fetched fields by using the `@client`-directive and TypePolicies

Assuming the typename returned from the query is "User":

Query:

```
query {
 userDetails {
  id,
  name,
  music {
   name,
   type
  }
  musicName@client
  musicType@client
}
```

Client setup:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      User: {
        fields: {
          musicName: {
            read(_, { readField }) {
              return readField('music').name;
            }
          },
          musicType: {
            read(_, { readField }) {
              return readField('music').type;
            }
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }),
  uri: "yourGraphqlServer.com"
});
```

Comment: was actually looking for something in this sort